# Cannot resolve variable described into serverless.yml and into serverless.com

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless, serverless-framework

I have some vars defined into a serverless service and correctly inherited into my stage parameters (at least, seems to be)

```
serverless deploy --aws-s3-accelerate --verbose
```

[image: my-stage-paramerters]

But when trying to deploy, i get this error:

```
Cannot resolve serverless.yml: Variables resolution errored with:
  - Cannot resolve variable at "provider.environment.NODE_ENV": Encountered invalid "--param" CLI option value: "MYSQL_APP_USER:admin". Supported format: "--param='<key>=<val>'"
```

I do nothing crazy into my serverless.yml

```
service: slack-api
frameworkVersion: '3'
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs18.x
  region: eu-west-2
  environment:
    NODE_ENV: ${param:NODE_ENV}
plugins: []
functions:
  statusGet:
    handler: handler.statusGet
    timeout: 29
    events:
      - httpApi:
          path: /status
          method: get
```

I hope any of you have an idea of what's happening. Many thx in advance. And of course, when i do this:

```
serverless deploy --aws-s3-accelerate --verbose --param="NODE_ENV=production"
```

no problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your configuration might be missing `org` and `app` settings to actually link your application to Serverless Dashboard. Please see the setup guide here: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/guides/dashboard#set-up